# Entity Framework, cannot add new object without specifying primary key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to use Identity to make the tables autoincrement the key upon insert. It worked nicely when I used a simple SQL query to insert a value.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[extrak] 
(
    [Id]                   INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [kategorianev]         VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [nev]                  VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [ar]                   INT         NULL,
    [szin]                 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    [tobbszor_hasznalhato] TINYINT     NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

However when I use C# code to add a value, I get an exception saying that I should `set identity_insert on` (I suppose this is when I want to specify a primary key, but I might have missed something). I tried setting It on also, but didn't work (right before calling the add method).

```
extrak extra = new extrak();
extra.kategorianev = categoryname;
extra.nev = name;
extra.ar = price;
extra.szin = color;
extra.tobbszor_hasznalhato = b;
Console.WriteLine("1");
DataBaseHandler.AddNewExtra(extra);
Console.WriteLine("2");
DataBaseHandler.SaveDB();
```

The exception happens on saving. Do I have to find the new primary key for myself, and insert that way? Or can I make Entity Framework handle It somehow?

Comment: That's an autogenerated class by the entity framework. You may see the sql structure above..

Comment: are you using entityframework if so what version...?

Comment: See question. "Entity Framework, cannot add new object without specifying Primary Key" It's the current last one available in the nuget. 6.2 if I am correct.

Comment: is `DatabaseHandler` the context?

Comment: so i assume you have an `edmx` file?  if you do and you are usind db first style of development, then maybe your edmx file is not up to date.  you can force a refresh by deleting, then re-adding the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mate got It. I had to update the model in VS to make It work.

After that the code above worked nicely.

[image]